# GNU screen is displaying totally incorrect dates and times in list output

Tags: screen

When I display screen sessions using screen -ls, I get sessions with timestamps that are totally incorrect.

My locale is

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

The current system date is

```
$ date
Wed Jan 17 07:23:43 PM UTC 2024
```

But for a screen session I just started, I get this

```
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        246095.pts-1.syst      (02/05/2024 01:19:19 PM)        (Attached)
1 Socket in /run/screen/S-user.
```

The system is running in an lxd container on a virtual machine and I am connected via ssh. Neither the other containers nor the virtual machine have this symptom.

Comment: in that screen session if you touch a file, does that file have the correct date and timestamp or is it in the future as well?

Comment: @Terrance the timestamp of a touched file in that session has the correct date and time.

Comment: Then I would file a bug against screen then.  `ubuntu-bug screen` and hopefully someone else is experiencing the same issue.  You could always re-install screen in that remote and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Bug filed. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/screen/+bug/2050938